# Как изменить элемент класса через QLineEdit в QT?

Tags: c++, qt

Являюсь новичком в сфере QT и пытаюсь практиковаться. Дошло до сигналов и слотов. Перейду к сути.

У меня есть класс `User`(User.h):

```
class User : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    static int counter;

    explicit User(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~User();
    QString getName();
    QString getPassword();
    int getAge();
public slots:
    void setName(QString name);
    void setPassword(QString password);
    void setAge(int age);
protected:
    QString name_;
    QString password_;
    int *id_;
    int age_;
};
```

User.cpp

```
#include "User.h"

User::User(QObject* parent) :
   QObject(parent)
{
   counter++;
   id_ = new int(counter);
}

User::~User()
{
   delete id_;
}

QString User::getName()
{
   return name_;
}

QString User::getPassword()
{
   return password_;
}

int User::getAge()
{
   return age_;
}

void User::setName(QString name) {
   name_ = name;
}
void User::setPassword(QString password) {
   password_ = password;
}
void User::setAge(int age) {
   age_ = age;
}

int User::counter = 0;
```

Через `QLineEdit`(введенную строку), нужно изменить состояние элементов в классе(`name_`, `password_`, `age_`).

Хедер класса `QtWidgetsAppilication`:

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <qmessagebox.h>

#include "ui_QtWidgetsApplication.h"
#include "User.h"

class QtWidgetsApplication : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtWidgetsApplication(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    void inputUser();
public slots:
    void inputUserName();
    void inputPassword();

private:
    Ui::QtWidgetsApplicationClass ui;
    User user;
};
```

(Знаю, что *User user* это было плохой идеей)

QtWidgetsApplication.cpp

```
#include "QtWidgetsApplication.h"

QtWidgetsApplication::QtWidgetsApplication(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.input, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &QtWidgetsApplication::inputUser);
    connect(ui.login, &QLineEdit::text, this, &QtWidgetsApplication::inputUserName);
    connect(ui.password, &QLineEdit::text, this, &QtWidgetsApplication::inputPassword);
}

void QtWidgetsApplication::inputUserName()
{
    QObject::connect(ui.login, &QLineEdit::textChanged, &user, &User::setName);
}

void QtWidgetsApplication::inputPassword()
{
    QObject::connect(ui.password, &QLineEdit::textChanged, &user, &User::setPassword);
}

void QtWidgetsApplication::inputUser()
{
    if (user.getName() == "John" && user.getPassword() == "1234") {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Programm", "You are our employee!");
    }
    else {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Program", "ERROR!");
    }
}
```

Прочёл про сигналы и слоты, и я использовал такой синтаксис:

```
QObject::connect(ui.password, &QLineEdit::textChanged, &user, &User::setPassword);
```

Однако, значения у меня не менялись, а когда дошло до проверки, то компилятор вместо значения видел мусор и выдавал `"ERROR"`, ибо это не удовлетворяло условию. Как можно исправить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `QLineEdit` нет сигнала `QLineEdit::text`. `QLineEdit` при изменении текста генерирует сигнал `textChanged(const QString &name)`, который можно обработать слотами:

```cpp
public slots:
    void setName(const QString &name);
    void setPassword(const QString &password);
```

Поэтому строчки:

```cpp
connect(ui.login, &QLineEdit::textChanged, &user, &User::setName);
connect(ui.password, &QLineEdit::textChanged, &user, &User::setPassword);
```

Надо перенести в конструктор вместо:

```cpp
connect(ui.login, &QLineEdit::text, this, &QtWidgetsApplication::inputUserName);
connect(ui.password, &QLineEdit::text, this, &QtWidgetsApplication::inputPassword);
```

Соответственно, данные методы не нужны:

```cpp
void QtWidgetsApplication::inputUserName()
void QtWidgetsApplication::inputPassword()
```

Метод `QtWidgetsApplication::inputUser()` желательно сделать слотом.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, теперь всё заработало.

Comment: @АнатолийЧехов если данный ответ, помог решить вашу проблему, то пожалуйста выберите его как "Правильный ответ", нажав на галочку слева от ответа.